# Анимация прогресс-бара

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, svg-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию прогресс-бара
https://codepen.io/mihail-kamahin/pen/YzKZjWd

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы из одной точки круга анимация начиналась сразу с двух сторон, на картинке я показал схематично, как я хотел это сделать
[image: Круг]

Но у меня не получается, я пытался ещё один круг создавать, поверх уже созданного, но получается какая-то каша. Кто уже работал с кругами на `svg`, возможно, знаете, как это сделать?

```js
function setProgress(percent, selector__circle) {
  const circle = document.querySelector(`${selector__circle}`);
  const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = circumference;

  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

var number = 125;

setProgress(number, '.progressbar__thumb');

click__me = document.querySelector('.click__me');

click__me.addEventListener('click', function() {
  setProgress(number += 25, '.progressbar__thumb');
});
```

```css
.progress__container {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
}

.progressbar__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #3E4153;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

.click__me {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__container">
  <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
    <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30">         </circle>
    <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30">         </circle>
  </svg>
</div>

<button class="click__me">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все можно сделать за счет одного лишь `stroke-dasharray`, корректно посчитав длины:

```js
function setProgress(percent, selector__circle) {
  const circle = document.querySelector(selector__circle);
  const total = Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
  circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${total*percent} ${total*(1-percent)*2}`;
  document.querySelector('svg text').innerHTML = (percent*100).toFixed(0) + '%';
}

var number = 0;

setProgress(number, '.progressbar__thumb');

document.querySelector('.click__me').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setProgress(number = number+0.1 > 1 ? 0 : number+0.1, '.progressbar__thumb');
});
```

```css
.progress__container {
 width: 140px;
 height: 140px;
}

.progressbar__track {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #3E4153;
 stroke-width: 3px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  transform:
    translate(32px,32px)
    rotate(180deg)
    translate(-32px,-32px);
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: yellow;
 stroke-width: 4px;
 transition: 0.2s;
}

.click__me {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress__container">
  <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
    <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
    <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
    <text x=32 y=32 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
  </svg>
</div>

<button class="click__me">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Я вроде бы понимаю, что в этом есть логика, что можно как-то этим управлять в строчке `${total*(1-percent)} ${total*percent}`, но какая здесь логика? Плохо понимаю, но очень интересно :D

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , да, если не сложно, я не понимаю как вы stroke-dasharray управляете. И я вроде не понял, почему у переменной total вы убрали умножение на 2

Comment: @StrangerintheQ чуть-чуть непонятно, почему на 2 умножается только пропуск?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97891/discussion-between---and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 6):

Как я понял из рисунка, - анимация прогресс бара должна начинаться из одной точки синхронно двумя линиями и заканчиваться тоже в одной точке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Расчет цифр в атрибуте stroke-dasharray**

При радиусе окружности `r="100"` длина окружности равна `C= 2 * PI * R = 628,3`

Половина окружности равна `314,15`

Анимация линии достигается с помощью увеличения черты от нуля до максимума - `628,3`

У атрибута `stroke-dasharray` первый параметр это длина черты, второй параметр это длина пробела, поэтому:

Чтобы получить в начале нулевую длину черты записываем:
 `stroke-dasharray="0 314.15 0 314.15"`

Длина черты `0` длина пробела -`314.15`  длина черты `0` длина пробела -`314.15`,  в итоге линию не будет видно.

Для максимального значения видимости линии нужно убрать пробелы :

`stroke-dasharray=0 0 628.3 0`

Для анимации линии записываем в `values` эти два значения `stroke-dasharray`

`values="0 314.15 0 314.15;0 0 628.3 0"`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var anim = document.getElementById('an');
btn.onclick = function () {
      anim.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Begin</button>
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
 <!-- Серая окружность, показывающая трассировку анимации. При необходимости можно убрать -->  
<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="6" fill="none" />
   <!-- Окружность, реализующая прогресс бар -->
<circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="purple" stroke-width="6" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 628.3" >
  <animate id="an"
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
  values="0 314.15 0 314.15;0 0 628.3 0"
  begin="indefinite"
  dur="4s"
  fill="freeze"/> 
 </circle>
</svg>
```

### Ещё пример основанный на этой технике

```css
.container
{
width:50%;
height:50%;  
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="10"  />  
       <!-- Средняя точка начала анимации в центре слева stroke-dashoffset="31.1" -->
 <path id="center" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="31.1" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_C.click" dur="4s" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
   <!-- Средняя точка слева stroke-dashoffset="-159.5" -->
     <path id="Left" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="-159.5" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_L.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>  
 
    <!-- Средняя точка слева сверху stroke-dashoffset="128.5" -->
     <path id="Top" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="128.5" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_T.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
     <!-- Средняя точка справа внизу  stroke-dashoffset="192.7" -->
  <path id="Bottom" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="192.7" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_B.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>   
 
        <!-- Средняя точка справа   stroke-dashoffset="223.9" -->
  <path id="Bottom" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="purple" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="223.9" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0" begin="btn_R.click" dur="4s"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
 
 
 
 <g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
    </g>  
 <g id="btn_C" transform="translate(3 0)">
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="24" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >C</text>
    </g> 
    
     <g id="btn_T" transform="translate(23 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue"/>
      <text x="24" y="95" font-size="10" fill="orange" >T</text>
        </g>  
  <g id="btn_B" transform="translate(43 0)">
 <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
  <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="dodgerblue" >B</text>
  </g>   
      <g id="btn_R" transform="translate(63 0)">
     <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
       <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="purple" >R</text>
    </g> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: А ведь действительно, не понятно как я так интерпретировал увиденное