# Как анимировать такой круглый прогрессбар?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, анимация

Нужно чтобы оранжевая линия прогресса у
первого круга прокрутилась и остановилась на 90 градусах (не делая полных оборотов),
у второго круга прокрутилась 2 полных оборота, а 3-й оборот остановился где-то на 45 градусах
и у третьего круга прокрутилась 10 полных оборотов.

P.S. плагины не подходят

Вот код

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);
 *, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 html, body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Lato', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}
 .set-size {
  font-size: 10em;
}
 .charts-container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}
 .pie-wrapper {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
 .pie-wrapper:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  clear: both;
}
 .pie-wrapper .pie {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip: rect(0, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
 .pie-wrapper .pie .half-circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.1em solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0, 0.5em, 1em, 0);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
 .pie-wrapper .label {
  background: #34495e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0.4em;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.25em;
  left: 0.4em;
  line-height: 2.8em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0.4em;
}
 .pie-wrapper .label .smaller {
  color: #bdc3c7;
  font-size: 0.45em;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: super;
}
 .pie-wrapper .shadow {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.1em solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 .pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
 .pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #e67e22;
}
 .pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie .left-side {
  transform: rotate(324deg);
}
 .pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie .right-side {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="set-size charts-container">
  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-90">
    <span class="label">90<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="set-size charts-container">
  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-90">
    <span class="label">90<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="set-size charts-container">
  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-90">
    <span class="label">90<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно с помощью css задать анимацию и поворачивать как вам угодно с помощью `transform: rotate`, а ещё можете посмотреть на ответ человека, как анимировать круг https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1017480/331312

Answer (score 2):

Как вам такое? Чтобы управлять временем, посмотрите как использовать `performance.now()` [JavaScript анимации](https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation)
Атрибут `data-circle` у `.progressbar__thumb` влияет на то, до какого числа будет идти анимация

```js
function start() {

  let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
    return requestAnimationFrame ||
      mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      oRequestAnimationFrame ||
      msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      }
  })();

  let dataCircle = document.querySelectorAll('.progressbar__thumb');

  function setProgress(percent, selector) {
    let circle = selector.querySelector('.progressbar__thumb');
    let total = Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
    circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${total*percent/100} ${total*(1-percent/100)*2}`;
    selector.querySelector('text').innerHTML = '<tspan>' + percent.toFixed(0) + '</tspan>%';
  }

  function circle(final, i) {
    let number = -1;
    i++;
    let selector = '.progress__container:nth-child(' + i + ')';
    let mainSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
    let myReq = null;

    function circleStep() {
      myReq = reqAnimFrame(circleStep);
      setProgress(number, mainSelector);
      if (number >= final) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
      }
      number++;
    }
    circleStep();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < dataCircle.length; i++) {
    let num = dataCircle[i].getAttribute('data-circle');
    circle(num, i);
  }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  start();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.cards__progress__bar {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress__container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.progressbar__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ededed;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #ff0036;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  transform-origin: center;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progressbar text {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.progressbar text tspan {
  fill: #ff0036;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="cards__progress__bar">

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- .progress__container -->

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="90" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- .progress__container -->

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="80" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- .progress__container -->

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="70" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- .progress__container -->

  </div>
  <!-- .cards__progress__bar -->

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```